# HIVE Correlated subquery

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to run below query in HIVE and getting error 'FAILED: SemanticException IN encountered with 0
children.  Same query is running in Mysql.

```
`Select ord.orno,
inv.pono,
inv.srnb,
ord.cur,
inv.invd,
cureff.rate
FROM  order ord 
JOIN invoice inv
ON(inv.orno = ord.orno)
-- Currency data
LEFT JOIN currrates cureff
ON (
cureff.cur = 'USD'
AND  cureff.stdt in (Select MAX(stdt) from currrates where stdt <= inv.invd AND cur = ord.cur )
)`<br />
```

Also, if I move the subquery to where clause it gives the error "Line 1:4052 Invalid table alias or column reference 'inv'".

```
`Select ord.orno,
inv.pono,
inv.srnb,
ord.cur,
inv.invd,
cureff.rate
FROM  order ord 
JOIN invoice inv
ON(inv.orno = ord.orno)
-- Currency data
LEFT JOIN currrates cureff
ON (
cureff.cur = 'USD' 
)
WHERE cureff.stdt in (Select MAX(stdt) from currrates where stdt <= inv.invd AND cur = ord.cur )`
```

Comment: Please explain what you want the query to do.  Sample data and desired results are also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the most recent USD row from the currency rates table.  For this, you should use window functions:

```
select . . .
from order o join
     invoice i
     on i.orno = o.orno join
     (select cr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cr.cur order by cr.stdt desc) as seqnum
      from currrates dr
      where cr.cur = 'USD'
    ) cr
    where cr.cur = o.cur and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: You are correct in your understanding. Only additional thing is I want to have a correlation between invoice date(invd)  from invoice table and currency rate table date field (stdt) where stdt should be the last date from the invoice date when currency rate is available. For example, if invd is July 2,2020 then I should get the exchange rate from currency rate table which was loaded on or just before July 2, 2020. So if currency rate table have rates for dates for June 30, 2020 and June 22,2020 then we should only pick exchange rate for June 30, 2020 for stdt.

Comment: @JaiGupta . . . Ask a new question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.